# Mongoose - post save hook not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my post save hook :

```js
profileSessionSchema.post('save',function(doc){
  console.log('POST SAVE HOOK')
})
```

And here is the code that should fire the post save hook :

```js
ProfileSession.findOne({prenom:'Georges'},function(err,profile){
  //... 
  Realisation.findOne({},function(err,realDoc){
    //...

    profile.realisations.push(realDoc);
    // And finally saving profile
    profile.save()
  })
})
```

And if it helps, here are my Schemas :

```js
const profileSessionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    prenom: { type: String, required: [true,'ce champ est obligatoire'], trim:true},
    realisations : [realisationSchema],
});
ProfileSession = mongoose.model('ProfileSession',profileSessionSchema);


const realisationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   profile_id :{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProfileSession'},
   wall : { type: String, enum:walls, required:true},
   pitch : { type: Number, min:1,max:maxWallsDiff, required:true,},
})
Realisation = mongoose.model('Realisation', realisationSchema);
```

I know the `profile.save()` method is called because I can see the changes on the profile doc after saving.
I don't understand what I am missing, I've read the documentation, looked at  the other posts dealing with this subject.

I have also tried to define the post hook callback with 3 arguments `(err, doc, next)`, and calling `next()` at the end of my callback definition, but it makes no difference.

Thank you for your help.
Cheers.

Comment: Does your hook fire when you have a simple setup without a reference to the other schema? I did a very quick test of your setup with just empty array in `realisations` and the save hook fires just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did as simple as possible with only the find query on Profile schema and a call to save method. But the post hook is not fired. I also tried with the post update hook, pre validate hook, post validate hook but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found what was the matter thanks to this post : 
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5073#issuecomment-287266986

It ends up that for mongoose > 4.8, hooks must be set BEFORE creating model !

That is to say

```js
// This must be define before mongoose.model(...)
profileSessionSchema.post('save',function(doc){
  console.log('POST SAVE HOOK')
})
ProfileSession = mongoose.model('ProfileSession',profileSessionSchema);
```

Thank you